# CSS box shadow query

Tags: css

I was fiddling around with CSS box shadow property. It seems like I can't have the top border shadow when I keep the angle at 90 degrees and apply some distance from bottom. Is there any way I can have top shadow along with bottom shadow.

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J6WTQ/)

```
<div class = "someclass">
</div>

.someclass {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 11px -5px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 11px -5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 11px -5px #000;
    margin: 20px;
    background: pink;
    width:300px;
    height:300px
}
```

Comment: With some distance between what?

Comment: What I meant was I already have bottom shadow few pixels away from the box. I wanted to keep the same pixels distance from bottom, but have top shadow as well.

Comment: I also don't understand what you want, just guess this may be what you want http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/J6WTQ/1/

Comment: I think you should read this: http://www.css3files.com/shadow/

Comment: You want a floating shadow? Maybe only with transforms. Take a look in this page, example 5: http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/css_box_shadow/

Comment: @Dimas Pante I was looking for something like in example 1, but with top shadow too.

Comment: Or take a look in example 7. Just need to remove the 'border-radius' from the :after,:before part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`box-shadow` allows multiple, comma-separated values. You can achieve the effect you want like so:

```
.someclass {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 11px -5px #000,
                0 -8px 11px -5px #000;
}
```

Make sure to also add it to the appropriate prefixed declarations:

```
.someclass {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 11px -5px #000,
                        0 -8px 11px -5px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 11px -5px #000,
                     0 -8px 11px -5px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 11px -5px #000,
                0 -8px 11px -5px #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was about to post an answer to my own question. I figured that out few mins ago.